# is there an XML standard to describe a component's characteristic

Tags: datasheet

I'm trying to automatize data extraction from datasheet's table. It's still a work in progress but I have good hope for it, some keyword "characteristic, min, max, symbol, test conditions,..." make them easy to spot. I just need more time to work on it.

Appart from the command line debug I'm using, I'm beginning to wonder what kind of usefull output format I should use. I think XML will be a good idea, and I would like to know if a standard that I could use already exist.

note : I'm using pdf2html (xml option) then python to process the file. I'm also using ODSlib to visualize the table recognition.

Comment: Eagle uses an [XML format](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/eagle-pcb-design-software/new-in-v6/). The DTD can be found in the software. There's also a copy [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/kicad-developers@lists.launchpad.net/msg02638/eagle.dtd). If you make your parts conform to that, you can bring them right into schematic capture and PCB layout.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there's a standard.  There's [14](http://xkcd.com/927/) of them - pick the one you want or create standard #15. As kyle said you can define the part information in terms of a specific piece of software's XML format but that doesn't buy you anything in *general*.

The best you can do is create something that works for your workflow.  That might mean working entirely within one piece of software's format (Eagle, TinyCAD, KiCad, etc.) or defining your own format and creating an XSL transform to change the XML into something that can be used by Eagle, etc. (Situation: there are 15 competing standards).